# Too many values to unpack error

Tags: python

Hi I am working with a list of tuple and I want to convert it to a dict. I am using list comprehensions, below is my code:

```
output_dict["leftovers"] = dict((position, token) for leftover in total_leftover
                                    for token, position in leftover)
```

I am not able to identify where I am going wrong.

```
total_leftover = [('alice',0),('carrot',4)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it wrong! Your list comprehension equates to

```
for leftover in total_leftover:
    for token, position in leftover:
        ...
```

Notice the issue is here with the second loop, `leftover` is a 2-tuple, and you are attempting to iterate over it, unpacking two elements at a time. This is not correct, as the tuple only has two scalars (you're trying to extract two scalars *per* iteration, and there's a difference).

If you're just mapping values to keys, then this should suffice. Reverse every tuple using `map` + `reversed`, and then pass the result to `dict`.

```
>>> dict(map(reversed, total_leftover))
{0: 'alice', 4: 'carrot'}
```

Alternatively, use a dict comprehension and swap the items.

```
>>> {y : x for x, y in total_leftover}
{0: 'alice', 4: 'carrot'}
```

---

As a matter of which is better to use, I'll do a little benchmarking. First, the setup -

```
x = np.arange(1000000) 
y = x.copy()
np.random.shuffle(x)

z = list(zip(x, y))
```

```
# solution with `map` + `reversed`
%timeit dict(map(reversed, z))
1 loop, best of 3: 965 ms per loop
```

```
# Daniel Roseman's solution with `dict`
%timeit dict((y, x) for x, y in z)
1 loop, best of 3: 341 ms per loop
```

```
# dict comprehension
%timeit {y : x for x, y in z}
1 loop, best of 3: 235 ms per loop
```

**The dictionary comprehension is by far the most performant method here**, because it is part of the language's literal syntax, rather than setting up a generator and delegating the dictionary creation to a function call.

Comment: the `map()` solution provides me a warning `Unexpected type(s): (Iterator[Iterator[_T]]) Possible types: (Mapping) (Iterable[Tuple[Any, Any]]) less... (Ctrl+F1 Alt+T) 
This inspection detects type errors in function call expressions. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Types of function parameters can be specified in docstrings or in Python 3 function annotations`

Answer (score 3):

The basic problem is you have too many levels of loop. If you want to do it as a list comprehension, you only need one level:

```
dict((position, token) for token, position in total_leftover)
```

Note this can be further simplified into a dict comprehension:

```
{position: token for token, position in total_leftover}
```

Comment: Which would be more optimized?

Comment: I guess the second one will be very slightly quicker as there is no function call.

Comment: @iam.Carrot The second one is also much faster for huge cases, i.e., where the function gets called just once so the function call is insignificant: https://ideone.com/JJtYYD I'm guessing because it doesn't create tuples all the time and because it's not going through a generator.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try unpacking the tuple a different way

```
dict((position, token) for (token, position) in total_leftover)
{0: 'alice', 4: 'carrot'}
```